# How to check if an array location is a certain number

Tags: c, function

I am in the middle of a project (in C) where I am programming a bingo game, and there is one last function to make, which is the one to check if there is a bingo or not.  I have an array of 5 x 5 generated random numbers, and I generate a random number through user input.  How do I make the array change that number (if it is in fact in the array) to 0, and then check if there is a bingo or not through user input?

Here is the code to generate the array

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        for(int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
            if(row == 2 && column == 2) {
                board[row][column] = 0;
            } else {
                int num = rand() %15 + 1 +(column * 15);
                for(int i = 0; i < 75; i++) {
                    if(num == used[i]) {
                        num = rand() %15 + 1 +(column * 15);
                    }
                }
                board[row][column] = num;
                used[used_counter] = num;
                used_counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
int generate_number(int boneyard[75], int *boneyard_counter) {
    int num = rand() %75 + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <75; i++){
        if(num == boneyard[i]);
        num = rand() %75 + 1;
    }
    boneyard[*boneyard_counter] = num;
    boneyard_counter++;
    return num;
}
```

And here is the code to generate the random number.

Answer (score 0):

You'd do something like this:

```c
    int found_match = 0;
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; ++row){
        for(int column = 0; column < 5; ++column){
            if(board[row][column] == num){
                board[row][column] = 0;
                found_match = 1;
                goto loop_end;
            }
        }
    }
loop_end:
    if(found_match){
    /*
    Check all diagonals, rows, and columns to see if any one of them contains only zeroes,
    stopping if you find that a diagonal/row/column that does in fact contain only zeroes
    and informing the player that they've won.
    */
    }
```